How to override generic method in subclass java
I am trying to refactor some code in order to reduce code duplication.
Currently I have a service that takes its own custom Payload class and returns its own Response class. And currently it is not one service class that does this but around 5 or 6. So that makes for a LOT of code duplication even though the body of the methods are literally the same, just the return type is different.
For example:
public class ServiceA {
    ResponseA getResponse(PayloadA){...}
}
public class ServiceB {
    ResponseB getResponse(PayloadB){...}
}
public class ServiceC {
    ResponseC getResponse(PayloadC){...}
}

Where the method bodies are literally word for word the same but because it is a post request using WebClient where the methods end with ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); return mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<>() {});, we are just copying the method again and again.
I tried to implement an abstract superclass called RestService and have two empty interfaces called RestResponse and RestPayload that each service can implement on their own but then how do I get the service class to return it's own Response type and not the RestResponse type which is just an empty interface?

EDIT - UPDATE:
So on a somewhat related note I solved my problem by doing the following:
public abstract class ParentService<R extends IResponse, P extends IPayload>{
  public abstract R getPayload(P);
}

public class ServiceA extends ParentService<ResponseA, PayloadA> {
  @Override
  public ResponseA getPayload(PayloadA){
    /***/
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();     
    return mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<>() {});
  }
}

Where each additional service is similarly inherited. And each response and payload implement the IResponse and IPayload interface models respectively.
Thank you for your suggestions!
(This final design decision was based on the current accepted answer, additional reading on generics and abstract classes in java as well as codebase design decisions)

I don't have enough info to be able to answer, what is the difference between payloads and responses of types A,B,C? Until we have the definitions of all of those classes, it wouldn't be possible to answer

That's exactly it, they don't have any fields in common at all, the only thing common across them is that they are just returned from the getResponse method. Similar for the Response class as well and this cannot change due to reasons I cannot go into.

Can you pass TypeReference<T> into the getResponse() method and return T?

Would something like this work for you?

T will return the type that the caller of the method wants.
Payload can be of any type

public class GeneralService {
    public <T> T getResponse(Object payload, Class<T> clazz){
        // do sth with payload
        return mapper.readValue(response, clazz);
    }
}


In case you want to be able to deserialize Collections as well, you can use TypeReference instead of Class:
public class GeneralService {
    public <T> T getResponse(Object payload, TypeReference<T> type){
        // do sth with payload
        return mapper.readValue(response, type);
    }
}

and then call it with the type, for example for list of strings:
generalService.getResponse(payload, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){})


So I've tried this method but when I override it in a specific ServiceXYZ class and try to use ResponseXYZ as the return type, it says Name clash: The method getResponse(Set) of type ServiceXYZ has the same erasure as getResponse(Set) of type RestService but does not override it

that is correct, overriding doesn't work with generic types - this is meant as replacement, NOT as override. You should only use this one method for all your services.

Ah I see thanks! I'll do some more reading on generics and oop :)

Wouldn't that TypeReference just point to Object all the time?

The generics for TypeReference don't do what you want here.

you guys are right, i updated the answer
